# Simple angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if someone knows who to start an angular app in node / bower but without all the e2e testing or all kind of things (angular-seed). I just want a simple structure that is somehow installed with node/bower and that can let me start the server and run.

Comment: Go at expressjs site and check it's docs. Most of the things for basic one is already there to get going.

Comment: I was thinking that exists something like npm install angular ...or somehing for a simple app structure with angular included...:-?

Comment: Then configure yeoman generator.

Comment: ok i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For spinning up a simple Angular app, I highly recommend the [Yeoman Angular.js Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme). It's a command line tool for generating "boilerplate" code, such as a boilerplate Angular framework to work with.